# CMake interface libraries propagating sources all the way up

Tags: cmake

In my CMake project, I have an interface library **A**, and I want it to be built as a part of static library **B**, so that **A** could use everything that **B** could use, and also use same compiler definitions. Afterwards, a final executable is built from library **B** and bunch of other libraries (say, library **A** which uses **B**).

In other words, I want the compilation steps to be like that:

- **libb.a**: *a.cpp*, *b.cpp* - separate logical CMake libraries are built as part of a single target
- **libc.a**: *c.cpp* - library **C** is built only from it's own file, and takes symbols from other libraries
- **test.elf**: *libb.a*, *libc.a*

Initially, I used CMake `INTERFACE` library to represent library **A**, and `STATIC` libraries for **B** and **C**.

```
add_library(a INTERFACE)
target_sources(a PUBLIC a.cpp)

add_library(b STATIC b.cpp)
target_link_libraries(b PUBLIC a)

add_library(c STATIC c.cpp)
target_link_libraries(c PUBLIC b)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test PUBLIC b c)
```

However, this has an undesirable side effect of putting a copy of `a.cpp` into *every* target instead of just **B**:

```
[  0%] Built target a
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/b.dir/b.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/b.dir/a.cpp.o
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libb.a
[ 33%] Built target b
[ 44%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/c.dir/c.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/c.dir/a.cpp.o
[ 66%] Linking CXX static library libc.a
[ 66%] Built target c
[ 77%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/a.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable test
```

This eventually leads to code duplication, with ELF file containing multiple copies of the same symbol. This duplication does not happen in this simple example, but actual project contains additional build steps which trigger such duplication.

Is there a way to stop the interface library propagation at **B**, so that *a.cpp* will only be compiled once as part of the **B** target?

Comment: Source file `a.cpp` is an interface of the library `a`. The linkage `target_link_libraries(b PUBLIC a)` means that every INTERFACE of the library `a` becomes the INTERFACE of the library `b`. So `a.cpp` becomes INTERFACE of `b`, and `a.cpp` is propagated to the library `c` which links with `b`. You may use PRIVATE linkage of `b` with `a`, so `a.cpp` won't be INTERFACE of `b`.

Comment: But this would hide include files of `a` as well? Is it possible to hide sources, but preserve includes?

Comment: "Is it possible to hide sources, but preserve includes?" No, CMake processes all INTERFACE properties of a target in the same way.  Either all such properties are propagated to the library's user or none of them. Your library `a` doesn't look as good design: You assign sources for it, but those sources cannot be compiled in the context of the library. Why don't assign those sources for library `b`, where they could be compiled?

Comment: Consider a low-level library like FreeRTOS. Is is tightly coupled to the application (i.e. includes are two-way, application includes FreeRTOS files, FreeRTOS includes configuration header), yet is is more clean to keep FreeRTOS as a separate logical CMake library.

Comment: In CMake it is better to think about the library as something which can be **compiled separately**. In that case `target_link_libraries` and propagation of INTERFACE properties works in "desired" way. *Partially-defined* libraries (which you achieve via `target_sources(INTERFACE)`) are usually not scalable in the sense of linking and properties propagation.